# How to list all Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I can see all the firebase dynamic links that are manually created in the firebase console.

However, I can't find those that are created with the firebase dynamic link rest api:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

Is it possible to list/see all the dynamic links created with the rest api?

Comment: Please file a feature request. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson is the scenario still this one? I cannot list all dynamic links I've created so far? Can I only take statistics through rest APIs link by link? This means that every time I create a dynamic link I must save it somewhere (read my DB backend), ain't it?

Comment: Any news about this topic?

Comment: Ping. Any news?

Comment: We would like to see a built in integration with something like BigQuery to store all the generated Firebase Dynamic Links.

Answer (score 3):

This is an intended behavior, but is a known feature request. Short Dynamic Links created programmatically are designed to be shared peer to peer. If there are multiple clients creating FDL, it's likely that the list of short links in the dashboard will be long. This can be challenging to navigate and track created links.

Short Dynamic Links created through Firebase Console on the other hand are more likely to be used in campaigns and makes sense to be tracked in the dashboard.

If you have more inputs regarding this function, you can file it as a feature request here https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: Any progress with the feature would be really helpful to get it up and running?

Comment: @MeLine a workaround for this feature is to store the generated links on your own i.e. store it via [Firebase Realitime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) or other preferred database solutions